# java.lang.NullPointerException when reading s3 with Hadoop (Scalding)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, nullpointerexception, scalding

Getting strange NPE when trying to read s3 with Scalding / Hadoop.  The paths are 100% correct.

Asking this question because it's surprisingly hard to Google and everytime I get this error I forget how I solved it.  So posting on SO so I can Google myself.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.listStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.listStatus(Globber.java:69)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1623)
        at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource.pathIsGood(FileSource.scala:57)
        at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource$$anonfun$hdfsReadPathsAreGood$1.apply(FileSource.scala:89)
        at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource$$anonfun$hdfsReadPathsAreGood$1.apply(FileSource.scala:89)
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.forall(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:70)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.forall(List.scala:84)
        at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource.hdfsReadPathsAreGood(FileSource.scala:89)
        at com.twitter.scalding.FileSource.validateTaps(FileSource.scala:101)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Job$$anonfun$validateSources$1.apply(Job.scala:158)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Job$$anonfun$validateSources$1.apply(Job.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Job.validateSources(Job.scala:153)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Job.buildFlow(Job.scala:91)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Job.run(Job.scala:126)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.start$1(Tool.scala:109)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:125)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool.run(Tool.scala:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at com.twitter.scalding.Tool$.main(Tool.scala:133)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your s3 credentials are not set correctly.  Make sure `fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId` and `fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey` are set, and correct.

Comment: Hit same problem, also the `s3n://` uri in my case

Answer (score 1):

This error is also seen doing glob searches. jets3 has to be tuned, I guess with max-keys or timeout options.

Comment: elaborate on this please?

Comment: @M-T-A I vaguely remember tuning `httpclient.connection-timeout-ms` and `httpclient.socket-timeout-ms`. Not absolute sure if this was related to this particular issue, though.